# Sharepoint 2013 Site Elements

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages, sharepoint-2013

I recently tested SharePoint 2013 on Office 365. It had an a list called "Site Elements" that allow editing the footer, header or create other elements. You can put a code in  the Master Page and the content of the element will be painted in the page.

Now i use my own Sharepoint 2013 server and the list does not appear in the site. In the examples  Master Pages,  the code appears but it draw anything.

How I can use this app/list on my server? I need to paint a footer and header configurable by the user.

A greeting.